# Use an exposed filter as contextual filter on another view

Tags: 7, views

The question is a pretty simple one, I've created a page-view with an exposed filter. The page-view itself contains a block-view. I was wondering if the value of the exposed filter (which is in the url) could be used as a contextual filter in the block-view.

So far I've tried 'get content ID from url' and  'get raw value'  but neither seem to work as the block-view returns no results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please follow below steps to achieve functionality that you are looking for.

1. Disable AJAX feature for view.
2. In the block view add a contextual filter and select type as Provide default value >> Type as php code.
3. In the php code read the exposed filter value using $_GET[]
4. Return the value you got from $_GET to contextual filter.

In that way you can able to pass exposed filter value to the contextual filter.

Comment: Works, cheers mate.