# how to value from one view to another view filter in drupal

Tags: 7, views

I want to pass the value from one view to another view's filter I have view 'filter' which is having the select box with taxonomy list as option 'category_taxonomy' having fruits,vegetables. I want to pass the taxonomy value to next view in on change event to filter the value in view 2.My both 'view1' and 'view2' are in same tpl.If I select the value from view1 I wat to send the argument to the second view and and filter the result and then reload only the second view(view2).

```
$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('service_line');
$terms = entity_load('taxonomy_term', FALSE, array('vid' => $vocabulary->vid));
// print_r($terms);
echo '<select class="filter"><option value="">select</option>';
foreach($terms as $data){
  echo '<option value='.$data -> name.'>'. $data -> name.'</option>';
 } 
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Please clarify the expected flow here. When user clicks on that filter in View 1, you want to redirect the user to View 2 and remember the selection they made in View 1?  Or do you want View 1 to process the filter selected and show filtered results but remember filter selection in case they go to View 2?

Comment: please check my updated post

Comment: So the taxonomy filter isn't really a filter - it acts more like a jumpmenu to View2 with the taxonomy value, correct?

Comment: yes u are absolutely correct

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create a jumpmenu in your view's template and add it to the page that way instead of trying to do it with filters.

So in your view's Advanced tab, click on "theming" option, and a dialog box will open with your view's template name. Copy the views.tpl from the views module to your theme and name it that template name. Inside this template you can now find the place you want to output this jumpmenu and add the tax_terms code you have above. Only instead of outputting the options as a form field, convert them to links using JS [here's one example](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_dropdown_menu.cfm). Or you can also create the jumpmenu as ctools like [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48516/create-jump-menu-with-more-options-using-programmatically).

Comment: I want to have the first view as it is and reload only the second view

Comment: in your comments above you said you want to navigate from first view to second view, this is exactly what this does

Comment: do you have both views as blocks showing at the same time on one page?

Comment: yes showing at same time in custom tpl for content type

Comment: ah, then maybe this [post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42437/use-an-exposed-filter-as-contextual-filter-on-another-view) could help.